# How to install PyObjC on Tiger?

Tags: python, macos, pyobjc

I installed Python 2.7 from python.org on OS X Tiger. It does not come with PyObjC, so I tried running easy_install pyobjc==2.2b2 as suggested on the website. However, it fails when trying to compile the FSEvents framework (which I understand is not available on Tiger). But the PyObjC website claims it works on Tiger. Is there any way to install it without the FSEvents framework (which I don't use anyway)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't test on Tiger unless I know that something is wrong.

Could you please file a bug at the PyObjC bug tracker (https://bitbucket.com/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc)?

I've fixed the installation of FSEvents in the 2.5 branch of pyobjc (which you can download at  https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/downloads), but I haven't tried to install on 10.4 myself yet so there may be other problems.